# Cached version of the site is different from "Fetch as Google" version

Tags: seo, google-search-console, fetch-as-google, google-cache

For some reason not all of the content that I can see at "Fetch as Google" appears in the cached version of the page. This same content also can't be found by Google Search.

What can be the reason for this? Google Webmaster tools say that the URL is submitted to index with status "complete":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Fetch as Google` delivers a screenshot of a site's loading state. Cache saves the site after all javascripts are executed, *all* means as well those, which run after the `load`is fired too. If any javascript modifies or hides content after `load` is fired , it will be visible in `fetch as Google`, but not visible in cache.

Comment: As well, Fetch as Google does not update the index directly anymore that I can see. What is seen in cache is what is stored as the HTML received by googlebot last. When Fetch as Google is used, the regular googlebot will visit the page again within a day or two and the cache will be updated at that time. So part of the answer is that this option is not immediate and will take a short bit of time to take full effect.

Comment: @closetnoc no, i haven't mean that `fetch as google` anyhow manipulates index. Its just a preview tool, which works like html snapshot done by headless browser without waiting for all javascripts are executed. Ah, ok, now i understand, what you mean: you mean this option include into index - this is something other as fetch as google.

Comment: I was sure you knew that... it was just that the OP may not have known. Sometimes my comments are purely for the OP and other future users and not necessarily directed at the poster of the answer. It is to add a point or to make sure that a point does not get missed. I just wanted future readers to know that pushing that particular button does not effect the SERPs and cache like it used to. My apologies! You give some of the best answers here!! No question.

Answer (score 1):

Google is much less predictable with its data recrawl times and I find a lot of their tools no longer work on the same sets of data they have on your website. I have seen Google take over a month to re crawl and update SERPs even after doing everything we could to get it to update it's records.